# WPF: Bind DisplayMemberPath in a combobox to the Item

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

Ok, this is kind of odd but this is basically what I need to do. I have a WPF control that is bound to a Document object. The Document object has a Pages property. So in my ViewModel, I have a CurrentDocument property, and a CurrentPage property.

Now, I have a combobox that I have bound to the CurrentDocument.Pages property and updates the CurrentPage property.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentDocument.Pages}"
    DisplayMemberPath="???"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPage, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ComboBox>
```

With me so far? All of this is fine except that I need the DisplayMemberPath to show "Page 1", "Page 2", etc.....

I tried creating a converter such as this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    string pageNumber = "Page {0}";
    return string.Format(pageNumber, value);
}
```

And tried to bind DisplayMemberPath to it like this:

```
DisplayMemberPath="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Index, Converter={StaticResource pgTitleConv}}"
```

But it still wouldn't show up in the combo box text!!!

There is no "Index" property but I don't know how to do this...How do I access the index of the item that the combobox is binding to...??????

Answer (score 24):

try this:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource pgTitleConv}}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

and in your valueconverter, if you can access the pages collection, you can use CurrentDocument.Pages.IndexOf(value) to get the index of the bound item. I'm sure there is a better way though.

Comment: Works but using a converter impacts performance.  I adapted above to use the binding  StringFormat feature. eg. <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:Page\: #0}}" />

Comment: @Darren Just curious, how much performance difference is there? How did you measure it? And where is the page index in the format string?

Comment: His example shows he's formatting a int value (page number/index) "string.Format(pageNumber, value);".  Your example demonstrates you don't need to provide a element name (Path=) to get the int value. So using the Binding's string formatter option to add the "Page" text in front of it was easy way to do (I was doing "Week x").

Comment: Performance: Getting Binding to format the value using own format function would reduce code. I could be wrong but I presume calling and executing the external value converter will add more code.  I voted up your answer as it was the one that shows you don't need the element name which was the thing that stumped me.

Comment: @Darren More code doesn't necessarily mean worse performance. However how would you get at the index of a page in its parent collection just using StringFormat? I mean i prefer StringFormat whenever possible, but for cases like this it can't really replace a Converter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Thanks to Botz3000 I figured out how to do this. (It's a bit wiggy, but it works fine.)

Suddenly, it came to me: the Page object has a Document object!! Doh!!

So, my `PageTitleConvert` just does this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        ImGearPage page = (ImGearPage)value;
        ImGearDocument doc = page.Document;
        int pageIndex = doc.Pages.IndexOf(page);
        pageIndex++;
        return string.Format("Page {0}", pageIndex);
    }
    return null;
}
```